# how to store resultset in String to be call in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, dao, resultset

how to store levelEmp that I've call in the select query to be store in level. Thus, I can call inside my LoginServlet.

```
      public class LoginDao {
public static boolean validate(String empID, String password) {        
    String status = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        conn = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

        pst = conn
                .prepareStatement("select levelEmp from employee where empID=? and password=?");
        pst.setString(1, empID);
        pst.setString(2, password);
        //pst.setString(3, levelEmp);

        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        status = rs.next(); //store levelEmp inside level

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } 
    return level;
}
```

this is my LoginServlet, is it correct how i call the level in DAO? I get error at String level.

```
String level = LoginDao.validate(n, p);
    if(LoginDao.validate(n, p) && level.equals("manager")){  
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
            session.setAttribute("user", n); // set session attribute of user name
        response.sendRedirect("admin/home_admin.jsp");
    } else if(LoginDao.validate(n, p) && !level.equals("manager")) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
            session.setAttribute("user", n);
        response.sendRedirect("home.jsp");
    } else {  
        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp"); 
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear,
Please elaborate or rephrase.

Answer (score 2):

You can not store resultset in string.

You have to do this to get **levelEmp** -

instead of doing this -  `status = rs.next();`

do this - `level = rs.getString("levelEmp");`

You have to choose **column** name from **resultset** to get that **column** value.

Comment: can you review my LoginServlet

Comment: have u changed the code of DAO according to my answer ?

Comment: yes, but i get error on return level, so i changed to return status. but i get error on my LoginServlet,

Comment: if level is null , then error will come and also which levelEmp column value is not there in database thats why u getting null in the level. Check database first

Comment: i've already add the database, but the servlet cannot connect to the database

Comment: cannot connect to the database....then i think there is problem in database connection.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way I would add following changes on code:

```
boolean level = false;


if(rs.next()){

  level = true;

}
```

So final code would look like following:

```
public class LoginDao {
public static boolean validate(String empID, String password) {        
String status = "";
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

boolean level = false;

try {
    conn = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

    pst = conn
            .prepareStatement("select levelEmp from employee where empID=? and password=?");
    pst.setString(1, empID);
    pst.setString(2, password);
    //pst.setString(3, levelEmp);

    rs = pst.executeQuery();


if(rs.next()){

  level = true;


}



    //  status = rs.next(); //store levelEmp inside level

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);

} 
return level;
```

}

Comment: how i suppose call levelEmp in my servlet? String level = LoginDao.validate(n, p);
        if(LoginDao.validate(n, p) && level.equals("manager")

Comment: can you review my LoginServlet?